# Struggling to find syntax error in select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My database is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patienttestdetail s(
    ptdid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    pid INTEGER,
    date TEXT,
    sugarlevel INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES patientdetails(id))
```

That script creates the table below.

```
ptdid  pid     date      sugarlevel 

1       1    12/05/2013      125
2       2    12/06/2013      325 
3       1    12/41/2012      125 
4       3    08/12/2012      135
5       2    04/05/2012      135 
6       1    05/12/2012      135
```

With my data entered, I now want to select the last row with pid=2.

I wrote the code like this:

```
cursor3=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM patienttestdetails WHERE pid="+patientId+" AND ptdid=(+SELECT MAX(ptdid) FROM patienttestdetails+)", null);
```

In the above query patientId=2 is fine, but causes a runtime exception.

Error:

> sqlite.SqliteException: near "&": syntax error :, while compiling:
>   SELECT * FROM patienttestdetails WHERE pid=2 AND ptdid =(+SELECT
>   MAX(ptdid) FROM patienttestdetails+)

Comment: what is && ......................

Comment: Use `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: @user2586693. You've just made an edit which hides the actual error you were running into from the question? (You changed '&&' to 'AND')

Comment: keep original error if you want to put solution heading solution and write it after question otherwise other viewer will find no problem in question

Answer (score 0):

not `&&`  its `and` 
and also what `+` `+` is doing there

```
    cursor3=
           database.rawQuery("SELECT * 
                              FROM patienttestdetails 
                              WHERE pid="+patientId+" and  ptdid in (
                                SELECT distinct MAX(ptdid) 
                                FROM patienttestdetails
                             )", null);
```

#### Before adding your query to your code you must first execute it with your database in sqlite database manager or some other manager if it executes then you should execute it on code

Learn more about sqlite [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.sqlite.org/&ei=VWcDUpvyLc2krQekroG4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEakQjCFFXx7pu-fq8qk9wUOlC1Bg&sig2=wY6cWEG8_23uYlYVyf6Npw&bvm=bv.50500085,d.bmk)

Comment: Active oldest votes there are three sorting you can sort and check who is copying as well as check my comments too  lol

Comment: Hi i wrote that but in the cursor not having any data.

Comment: now try this it may change or you can check you database whether the condition satisfies or not

Answer (score 0):

You should **stick to general coding style** and use `AND` instead of `and` and `&&` is not used in SQL either.

Obviously you want to get the latest row and try that with a subselect and `MAX()`.

**Rewrite your query** to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
"SELECT *
 FROM patienttestdetails
 WHERE pid=" + patientId + "
 ORDER BY ptdid DESC
 LIMIT 1"
```

...would make more sense.

Comment: Have you checked that one?